# Keeping trademark symbol in a dataframe column output

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've been trying to use Python and Pandas to take a csv as input, clean the dataset, and assign the output to a new csv file. One of the columns in the original csv has trademark symbols. When I export the new csv, the columns sometimes have Â™ instead of just the trademark symbol, or sometimes they're turned into Ã¢Â„Â¢. This is how I imported the original csv and exported the new csv:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("original_df.csv", encoding='latin1',dtype='unicode')
```

This is how I exported a new dataframe to csv:

```
df_new.to_csv('new_test_df.csv', index = False)
```

How do I export the string without the extra symbols (i.e. how it was in the original)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed this same problem. Answer and explanation can [be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57062260/11162501)

Quick answer is to use encoding "utf-8-sig"